# Text Editor to select based lines inbetween user defined characters

Tags: text-editors, selection

I have a text file with over 184 thousand lines.
This is the output from a particular application and is basically the dump of the database in JSON format. I need to select the lines which are between curly braces. For example, my file would have some text like this like this:

```
{..
..
...
}

{
...
....
.....
  |
  30,000 lines later
  |
...
...
}
```

I need to select these 30,000 odd lines and paste it somewhere else.
Is there any Text editor which lets you do a selection based on edge characters?

I work with both Linux & Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Vim](http://www.vim.org/) will all you to select everything between matched brackets when the cursor is over one of the brackets with:

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd> (start a line selection)

<kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>5</kbd> ("bounce" to other bracket)

Then hit <kbd>y</kbd> to copy or <kbd>d</kbd> to cut, and <kbd>p</kbd> to paste.

Gvim, the graphical version of Vim is available on both Windows and Linux.

To install on Ubuntu or Debian:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vim-gnome;
```

Then run with the icon or:

```
gvim &
```

But what are you actually wanting to do with this text?  It sounds like a simple program might be a better bet?